# How to request and get value from HATEOAS

Tags: javascript, json, spring-hateoas, hateoas, openproject

I am newbie to using hypermedia rest API (on openproject).

I retrieved from HATEOAS (Hypermedia As The Engine Of Application State) with javascript and show the result to HTML but not known how.

Example for my api url:

```
http://<my_domain>/target/api/v3/projects/design/work_packages
```

I have followed https://www.chillyfacts.com/javascript-send-http-getpost-request-read-json-response but javascript only work for JSON, can't work for "HAL + JSON"

==> My Question:

1. Can javascript work with HATEOAS?

   - (If have) Which libraries on javascript to use?
   - (if not) Which programming language work with hal+json?
2. Which programming language for design HATEOAS on the server-side?

[< This is my api in openproject >](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcK6I.png)

Thanks!

Comment: HATEOAS basically describes the HTML/HTTP Internet around 1995. JavaScript is essentially a great example of a thing that the original REST paper was arguing *against*. People now who talk about "REST" really aren't talking about REST as originally envisioned. The term is essentially meaningless in 2020, and yes I know I'm making an iconoclastic statement.

Comment: thanks for your info so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already have the answer!
I have used angular2 programming language with the Typescript (https://angular.io) and saw:

1. Very easy to render data from the Typescript (process the logic) to HTML
2. The library for work with the HATEOAS API is the "ketting" (https://github.com/badgateway/ketting/wiki/Getting-Started)

==> So, this topic was resolved!